# Is it safe to swim during the healing period of a nipple piercing?

Tags: recovery, swimming, nipples, body-piercings

I am a male and I am considering to get one of my nipples pierced. I swim regularly (4-5 times a week) in a swimming pool and I was wondering if there is any problem with swimming during the healing period of the piercing.

Is it possible or should it be avoided? In case it is possible, should any special precautions be taken?

P.S. I haven't still decided if I am going to get the piercing or not, that's the reason why I haven't still asked a professional about it.

Comment: I would also tell you that it is great to be informed before hand, but to consult the professional. The infection risk can be life long and life threatening. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Breastfeeding Management for the Clinician: Using the Evidence](https://books.google.com/books?id=aXDSJdZ8KbkC&pg=PA554&lpg=PA554&dq=8%20to.12%20month%20healing%20for%20nipple%20piercing&source=bl&ots=A-XaEJak9L&sig=ZDQ_6-JmlJZeXUUIDc7Quyn-V7w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2pvOzuc3MAhUKLyYKHZUdCygQ6AEIOjAJ#v=onepage&q=8%20to.12%20month%20healing%20for%20nipple%20piercing&f=false)

According to this link 6 to 12 months healing are for a nipple piercing, but some can take as long as 18 months.

[Definitely avoid it.](http://www.medicalearpiercing.com/faqs/#toggle-id-8)

> Chlorine and the bacteria in unchlorinated waters may both irritate
>   your newly pierced ears. It is therefore recommended that you wait 2-3
>   weeks after your piercing.

And while that is about ear piercings, nipple and ear piercings both break skin integrity and so present the to risk of infection.

According [Nhs.UK](http://www.nhs.uk/chq/Pages/2297.aspx?CategoryID=52) any water including lakes and hot tubs can cause harm. Harm including massive life threatening infections that can lead to [death or disability](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3994836/). And states:

> You should avoid swimming for at least 24 hours after having a
>   piercing, and ideally until it has healed properly. While it's still
>   healing, it's important to keep the piercing dry as there's a risk of
>   infection.

While, nipple healing times are defintely not the same as ear or tongue piercings probably I would consult on that and possible bandages to wear if you decide to swim during the healing time. But you should seek the council of a professional and for go swimming, it is better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: I know a young lady who will never nurse a baby with her left nipple. Her pierce became infected and left her nipple damaged and non-functional for life. The point being that warnings about infection aren't overblown.